# What is the purpose of an arrow function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, arrow-functions

I realize this may be a stupid question but I haven't been able to find an explicit explanation anywhere. In my case, I have 2 React components.
Say my main component has a method called doSomethingOnClick(). Now I am calling another component and passing it a prop by calling this method. My question is **why** do I need to do:

```
<Component someprop= {(arg) => this.doSomethingOnClick(arg)}
```

Why can;t I do this instead ?

```
<Component someprop= {this.doSomethingOnClick(arg)}
```

Even in the component which receives this prop makes use of a similar syntax. So why do I do

```
someprop = {(arg) => props.doSomethingOnClick(arg)}
```

instead of

```
someprop = {props.doSomethingOnClick(arg)}
```

The way I understand it is the same method is being called with the same argument leading to the same result. (I hope) Is this something that the syntax simply demands and **must** be done or is there some **special reason** for this ?

Comment: It's to ensure that the calling context (the `this`) inside the callback (eg, `doSomethingOnClick`) is the instance. If the callback isn't using `this`, then it doesn't serve a purpose. You can also achieve it by binding the method to `this` in the constructor, or using class field syntax.

Comment: If you use `someprop= {this.doSomethingOnClick}` rather than a function that calls `doSomethingOnClick` *and* you don't bind in the constructor *and* you don't use class fields for the method *and* you reference `this` inside the callback, you'll run into errors.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand...Why does it not serve a purpose ? If i bind the function and use it in the same class, will I still have to use the arrow function in the second component which used the same method ?

Comment: No - if you use *any* one of those techniques, you won't have to use any of the others, because the `this` inside the method will be correct (or not needed).

Comment: okay so the only point is that 'this' doesnt work well with arrow functions. So if i bind the method in the constructor I can directly use this.method and props.method in both the same class and some other class to which it has been passed correct ?

Comment: Not exactly, it's that `this` with anything *but* an arrow function is based on calling context, rather than being lexically inherited from the outer scope - and by default, the calling context for an event handler will be `window`. It's not a React thing, it's a DOM thing

Comment: What documentation do I need to read to get an understanding of events and methods used to handle them ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205205/discussion-between-harsh-limaye-and-certainperformance).

Comment: If you already have a named function/method I personally prefer to do: `someprop= {this.doSomethingOnClick.bind(this)}` or if it's a pure function (not a method): `someprop= {doSomethingOnClick}`

Comment: @HarshLimaye It depends on where exactly are you using the Arrow function. If the Arrow function is used in the render method, then they create a new instance every time render is called just like how bind would work.